# How to determine the best setting for spark running on a single node?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark, spark-shell

I have 55 GB data that needs to be processed. I'm running Spark-shell on a single machine with 32 cores and 180GB RAM (No cluster). Since it's a single node both- Driver and Workers reside in the same JVM process and by default use 514 MB.

I set spark.driver.memory to 170G

```
spark-shell  --driver-memory 170g
```

I'm doing a map operation followed by group_by and then agg and write to a parquet file. And it's still stuck at
[image]

Is there anyway to optimize the performance by changing the spark.executor.memory or changing the number of cores used instead of using Master[*]? How can one determine the optimal setting for a given task and data size? what values in --conf files I should be exactly tweaking?

In short, how to force spark to use all the resources available in the best possible way?

Comment: You can check the CPU and memory usage in `top` or something like that. I think spark by default uses all the cores available. The process might be slow because of both slow I/O while reading that large chunk of data, and/or slow computation due to the sheer amount of computation involved.

Answer (score -2):

Changing spark.executor.memory doesn't take effect if you're running on a single computer. You need to have an actual cluster. You can add more nodes to the cluster to lower the number of partitions and speed up processing.

Comment: I only have a single node/machine